# Как разработать процедуры преобразования видов хранения графов с выдачей результатов на дисплей?

Tags: c++, графы, любой-язык

У нас есть 3 вида хранения графов: матрица инцидентности, смежности и список. Нужно реализовать переход из любой матрицы в любую (желательно без выделения памяти в случае C++, но разницы на каком языке будет реализована процедура - нет). Проблема заключается именно в принципе перехода от одного к другому :(
В примере кода переход от матрицы инцидентности к матрице смежности

```
#include <iostream>
#define V 4
#define E 4

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int I[V][E] = { {1, 1, 0, 0}, { 1,0,1,0 }, { 0,0,0,1 }, { 0,1,1,0 } };
    int count = 0;


for (int j = 1; j <= V; j++)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= V; i++)
    {
        if (I[i][j] == 1) {
            count += 1;

        }
    }
}



int count2 = count / 2;

int SM[100][100];

for (int i = 1; i <= count2; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= count2; j++) {
        SM[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

for (int v = 1; v <= V; v++)
for (int e1 = 1; e1 <= E - 1; e1++)
if (I[v][e1])
for (int e2 = e1 + 1; e2 <= E; e2++)
if (I[v][e2]) {
    SM[e1][e2] = 1;
    SM[e2][e1] = 1;
}
//_________________________OUTPUT
cout << "\nSM matrix:\n" << endl;
for (int j = 1; j <= count2; j++)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= count2; i++)
    {
        cout << "  " << SM[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Ну начните работать, сделайте заготовку, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться

Comment: Уже сделал, сейчас добавлю, правда там всё внутри main, а не процедурой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так вроде вы понимаете, что нужно делать. Только почему нумерация с единицы?

Для создания матрицы инцидентности **I** из матрицы смежности **A** для начала нужно посчитать единички в **A** и разделить пополам - это будет число рёбер, число столбцов в **I**. Далее заводите счётчик рёбер `CE`, обходите половину **А** выше диагонали, и для `A[i][j]==1` ставите единички в паре `I[i][CE], I[j][CE++]`

Для списка **L** в **A**: поставьте единицы в те ячейки `i`-й строки **А**, номера которых которых присутствуют в списке смежности для `i`-го элемента (`L[i]`).

Для **L** в **I**: как и раньше, посчитайте общее количество, пополам, сделайте **I**. Затем в `i`-м списке берутся только элементы `j`, **большие**, чем `i`, и ставите единички в паре `I[i][CE], I[j][CE++]`

**A** или **I** в списки вроде нетрудно перевести, да?